# Ubuntu stuck at black screen with pink diagonal lines after selecting "Try Ubuntu." (Update - Still need help)

Tags: boot, windows, hard-drive, windows-vista

I'm trying to follow the instructions from this site (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/), but after selecting "Try Ubuntu", I'm stalled at a black screen with pink diagonal lines and it's been this way for almost a half-hour now. The CD stopped moving pretty early on too. My mother's Windows Vista is dead and we're trying to recover all of her work related files off it. Does anyone have any solutions? Her office IT says that the more you boot up a computer with a damaged hard drive, the more files you lose and she's already booted it up four times now (not including this time).

If anyone can help out, I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

**Update: Ubuntu wouldn't work on her computer (I'm thinking graphics card issues) so I installed Lubuntu instead. I got Lubuntu to work on her computer, and it even let me mount and access the hard drive, however, when I click a folder, it tells me something like "Corrupt" and I selected the file manager to open it, but now it's saying "input/output error" when I try to access the users folder. Any idea why it's doing this?
Another Update: I made the mistake of giving in to my mother "looking at it" and she ejected the hard drive because she thought it was a "down arrow". I restarted and now it's not even recognizing it. I'm gonna guess that's probably not a good thing, and I'm really upset and frustrated at this point.**

Comment: in the end when you boot a livecd until you mount the drive it does nothing, and if the drive is truly damaged that badly you can't really recover the files without actual physical forensics, though if the drive is in a state you can load ANYTHING from it it is fine and you don't have to worry about booting from basically anything

Comment: also you might need to try reburning the disk at this point, it sounds like that is the problem.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. Her computer starts up, you can press F8 and the like and get to those screens and we even made it to the recovery screen once but it did not recognize a hard drive. When you actually try to go to safe mode or last known good configuration, the blue screen flashes and it restarts itself, rinse/repeat. I'll try reburning the CD as you said, thank you! I'll also try Lubuntu as well if it is the graphics.

Comment: if it still boots at all the disk is not the main problem, my father works at dartmouth college and I know that ITs can sometimes try and freak people out like that just to be safe

Comment: Now I'm having problems getting my laptop to even boot Ubuntu from the CD. It doesn't recognize I have a CD drive when at the boot screen so I can't even check if the CD is the problem or not. Go figure. I'm just going to go ahead and try Lubuntu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try reburning the disk, and if that doesn't fix it it may be a problem with the graphics card or something. You could try using lubuntu or a puppy linux livecd to copy the files off the disk as well as it doesn't require nearly as much graphics work.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try again. I'm gonna try running it on my laptop this time and if it doesn't work it probably does need reburned.

Comment: Okay, so I got Lubuntu to work on her computer, and it even let me mount and access the hard drive, however, when I click a folder, it tells me something like "Corrupt" and I selected the file manager to open it, but now it's saying "input/output error" when I try to access the users folder. Any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: try installing gparted and run a disk check on it, or if you have an external disk try copying the partition over then we can try stuff to try and recover it

Comment: I don't have an external drive but we were going to use a USB to transfer files from it. I had updated that my mom made a mistake and ejected the hard drive and now it's not showing up anymore after restart. How would I get gparted on there once I do find the hard drive again?

Comment: you open the livecd and go into the software center (or equivalent, I use muon in kubuntu) and install gparted, but remember it will disappear after a reboot as it is into the ramdisk

Comment: Thank you for that. Should I take the hard drive out and hook it back up again, because it's just not showing it anymore no matter what I try.

Comment: you may need to reboot with the drive in as sata does not officially recognize drives as hot-swappable and neither does ubuntu, so if it isn't there at boot it won't show up at all

Comment: Okay so I took the CD out and tried to restart, and the computer is saying "DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER." I'm really regretting letting my mom touch anything. I'm doing a search on it and none of it applies to my situation.

Comment: it seems the computer isn't detecting any bootable media. Is it possible to move the hard disk and cd to another computer? also please wait a little while I have tennis practice

Comment: All I have is a laptop. I may end up just having my mom take the hard drive to someone to get the data off it. I really appreciate you helping me, have fun!

Comment: is the other computer a laptop?

Comment: No, her computer is a desktop.

Comment: so if you go to a friend's then run the procedure I outlined with the hard drive connected and you should be able to recover the files

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm going to try that! I appreciate it!